# Invalid look-up value.\n\nA look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again (trying to assign lookup value to list item)

Tags: 2010

I am using word automation services to convert docxs to pdf. This works fine, and I add the metadata (Strings) to the resultant pdf. However, how can I add lookup value fields to the document's list item?

Item["Field"] = LookUpField[1]; (where "Field" is of type Lookup).

LookupField is a collection of type List and stores the value of the list item field from the docx value.

I get this error:

ex = {"Invalid look-up value.\n\nA look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again."}

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup values should be either integers which represent ID of the target element in the lookup list, or strings formatted as `id;#title`.

For example:

```
item["FieldName"] = 10;
item["FieldName"] = "10;#Target item title";
```

Thus I would recommend you to check in debugger, what values do you have in the `LookUpField` collection.

Also you could try using [ParseAndSetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.parseandsetvalue.aspx) method, i.e.:

```
var field = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("FieldName");
field.ParseAndSetValue(item, value);
```